# How do I get the image of an excel chart using Microsoft Graph API ? from c#

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I have implemented the following method in c#

```
    public static async Task<WorkbookWorksheetChartsCollectionResponse> GetChart(string idItem, string nameSheet)
    {
        var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();

        var chart = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[idItem]
            .Workbook
            .Worksheets[nameSheet]
            .Charts["Chart 1"]
            .Image(640, 480, "fit")
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

        return chart;
    }
```

but I get the following error when returning the chart [the error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ft7e.png), 
this is the class by microsoft graph api
[class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwLo2.png)

Comment: According to the docs, it seems as though it returns the image as a base64 string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chart-image?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: yes, that's right, but the implementation I'm doing with the api library, is the idea to use it for it, the documentation shows the example with url's, and I need to do it with microsoft graph

Answer (score 0):

It appears `msgraph-sdk-dotnet` (`v.1.21.0`) doesn't generate the correct URL for [`Chart: Image` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chart-image?view=graph-rest-1.0)  and the following error occurs:

> The type 'microsoft.graph.image' specified in the URI is neither a
>   base type nor a sub-type of the previously-specified type
>   'microsoft.graph.workbookChart'

The following comment could be found in [`ExcelTests.cs`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/fc2116b4ad335ab25f8df8f4b0dce8c9950eda78/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Requests/Functional/ExcelTests.cs) regarding same issue:

> Workaround since the metadata description isn't correct as it states
>   it returns a string and not the actual JSON object, and since the
>   service doesn't accept the fully qualified name that the client emits
>   even though it should accept the FQN.

and the following workaround to get chart image

```
var chartResourceUrl = graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[itemId]
         .Workbook
         .Worksheets[nameSheet]
         .Charts[chartName]
         .Request().RequestUrl;


 var urlToGetImageFromChart = $"{chartResourceUrl}/image(width=400, height=480)";
 var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, urlToGetImageFromChart);
 await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
 var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     JObject imageObject = JObject.Parse(content);
     JToken chartData = imageObject.GetValue("value"); 
     //...
 }
```